# How to fix "Resource temporarily unavailable" error running "sudo apt-get update"?

Tags: apt, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing “Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock)

When I try to run `sudo apt-get update` this is what it shows; what should I do?

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: where is that exact question kindly post the link to exact question.